# Github actions timeout a single step/job from a workflow and still run later jobs/steps

Tags: timeout, github-actions

Hello for my github workflow the current process is

1. Start a VM
2. Run a load test
3. Turn off VM

The reason for this is to save costs of having the VM on when it is not being used. The current task I'm working on is handling if step #2 hangs. I know I can use [timeout-minutes](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepstimeout-minutes) to cause it to end earlier than the default 6-hour timeout, but it appears that this ends the process rather than just the single step.

Regardless of the test hanging I still want step #3 to still occur and turn off the VM.

Thanks for assistance if anyone knows how to do this natively!

Comment: Have you used `timeout-minutes` in conjunction with [`continue-on-error`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error)?

Comment: Along with the `continue-on-error` config `Azeem` shared, you could also eventually add a `if: always()` in the last step to be sure the step is [always](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#always) run.